# Cannot enable more than 2 simultaneous Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, remote-access, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

Windows Server 2012 is unable to allow more than 2 simultaneous Remote Desktop Connections:

Instead of editing the group policy :

- **"Limit Number of connections to 999999"**
- Disabling **"Restrict Remote Desktop Services Users to a single Remote Desktop Services session"**
- successful ***gpudate*** on cmd

So, as far as I know Terminal Services are different from the present scenario, so I guess in this situation I do not need to buy licenses and CALS for extended number of users? 

N.B :-***Correct me if I am wrong as I am still a novice  :-)***

Comment: Is this it? [If the RD Session Host role service is not installed on the computer, a connection can only allow a maximum of two simultaneous remote connections to the computer.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753380.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but when I open Administrative tools window I cannot find the 'Remote Desktop Services', what does it mean? I do not have the service installed? Please show me the path as I am totally confused

Comment: At the very least, you need to install the Remote Desktop Session Host role on the server in order to have more than two simultaneous RDP sessions. You'll also need to install the Remote Desktop Licensing role on a server and you'll need the appropriate number and type of RDS CAL's.

Comment: Thanks for the info @joeqwerty, isn't it possible to enable multiple access through the RDS Host role install only? As u have told "At the very least"

Comment: `At the very least` is just a figure of speech. What I mean is that you need to install the Remote Desktop Session Host role and you also need to install the Remote Desktop Licensing role and you need RDS CAL's.

Comment: :-) .. thats it .. all I wanted to know

Comment: joeqwerty has it right. The default install of Windows Server only allows 2 concurrent RDP connections. To do more you need to install the services mentioned and add CALs for as many as you want.